# Iterate through multiple sheets from stored array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I've seen multiple posts about this, but none seem to directly address what i'm looking to do (in a way that I understand atleast).

I'm looking to iterate through my various sheets and format the data in each sheet into a table; seemingly very simple, but i'm struggling with storing the sheets into an array for easy iteration through a for loop.

I'm passing in the `formatSheetsArray` from the main, which has the following data stored in it:  `formatTablesArray = Array(lo.Name, wa.Name, sevenA.Name, oh.Name, at.Name, ob.Name, ra.Name, cvr.Name, ln.Name)`

The sheets have all had their code names changed for easier manipulation, but now i'm confused how I should iterate through them from an array standpoint.  There are other sheets in the workbook so I can't use `sheets.count` and I attempted to use `For Each Worksheet In formatSheetArray` and I received the same error I'm receiving now, which is Error 424 Object required.  Any thoughts?

```
Private Sub FormatOiTables(ByVal formatSheetsArray As Variant, ByRef cmeBook As Workbook)

    Dim loopCounter As Integer, lastRow As Integer


    For loopCounter = 0 To UBound(formatSheetsArray)

        lastRow = cmeBook.Sheets(formatSheetsArray(loopCounter)).Cells(formatSheetsArray(loopCounter).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for populating `formatTablesArray`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It's up in the question there, but I actually just managed to achieve a solution that works.  If anyone has any critiques of it (i'll post in a moment) i'd love to hear it.

Comment: You were getting an error because you are using `cmeBook` instead of `cmeDataBook`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout There is no direct reference in the OP's code regarding perhaps a variable cmeDataBook. I wonder how you guessed rightly that it should be cmeDataBook instead of cmeBook . Its just for my learning.

Comment: By looking at his answer @skkakkar ;)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Oh! I should have correlated the things on time-scale. Heartfelt thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can make and use an array of worksheet-objects:

`formatTablesArray = Array(lo, wa, sevenA....)`

and then do

```
for each tbl in formaTablesArray
    tbl.
next
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that I just got working for the problem above. As @Siddhart pointed out as well I had a typo for my `cmeDataBook` Workbook, which was initially typed in as `cmeBook`. Thanks to all!

```
Private Sub FormatOiTables(ByVal formatSheetsArray As Variant, ByRef cmeDataBook As Workbook)

    Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    For Each WshtNameCrnt In formatSheetsArray

        cmeDataBook.Sheets(WshtNameCrnt).Activate

        With Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt)

            lastRow = .Cells(Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        End With

        MsgBox (lastRow & " " & WshtNameCrnt)

    Next WshtNameCrnt


End Sub
```

Comment: Your original code will work. There is a typo in the original code... Your `cmeBook` should  be `cmeDataBook`

Comment: Also you may want to change `Dim lastRow As Integer` to `Dim lastRow As Long`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Biggest lastRow could really ever feasibly be would be approximately 100 rows.  I'm finding the lastRow to create dynamic tables on each sheet.